# How to Create Custom "type" attribute for textboxfor in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working in MVC. I have stuck badly in a situation. 
As we know,

```
    @Html.Textboxfor
```

have a property named **type** which detects the type of input which the textbox can take.

For Ex: **type = "email"** takes email as input and if validation fails it shows error message like "Please Enter valid Email Address".

**type = "number"**  takes number only as input and shows validation message if text will use.

I want that my textbox will  take Mobile/Phone numbers(with country codes and without country codes as well. e.g. +9177777777777).

So Can i create my own custom **"type"** attribute which can accomplish above task and can generates my own validation message if validation fails ?

Answer (score 3):

The attribute `type` you are talking about is an attribute of `<input />` html element. As per HTML5 specifications there are only several valid values this attribute can take. See them here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

So, you cannot just add any sort of "custom" value which would imply some automatic validation by the browser. What you want, I think, is to be able to validate input against a specific phone number format. For that you need to use `[RegularExpression]` attribute (entirely different thing, but named the same) on the property in your model class. This, coupled with unobtrusive client side validation, would give you the behaviour you want.

### Update

Different values of `type` attribute enable you to invoke browser's native client side validation support. For custom formats, use general `type="text"` and put regular expression in the `pattern` attribute. Browser will display an error popup with the message from the `title` attribute.

So, in your view you could have something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { pattern = "\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}" })
```

Assuming the property name is `PhoneNumber`. Your regular expression will be different depending on the actual format you want to support.

---

I think it's worth mentioning another couple of attributes related to validation:

- `required`
- `maxlength`

More about native client side validation here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you'll find here the solution you prefer : 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Edit :
I was thinking about your question, i think i was wrong.
Your can add what you call "`Custom Type`" using the Mvc "`Template`".

For example : 
Create a "`DisplayTemplates`" directory into the "`Shared`" folder of your view.

Inside this new one, create a `PartialView` typed with your custom Model.
Put everithing you want into your new partial view/model to do what you espect.

After into your main view page. Juste call `@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.YourNewCustomModel)` and MVC does the rest.
For sure, your new CustomModel has to be a part of the main calling page model.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm missing something, but you could simply say the following (replacing the ??? accordingly):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.???, new { type = "???" })
```

Comment: While that certainly creates a custom type attribute, it doesn't actually do what he wants, because you can't just make up types.